# Process won't start with double quotes

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I'm trying to copy a folder to a priviledged one (C:\Program Files (x86))

For that I run a Batch file as administrator through a C# function

Batch file is just:

```
robocopy %1 %2 /E
```

When writing manually on windows cmd folder and subs are copied well but it doesn't work in my program, proc.start() closes instantly

```
String SourcePath = @"Z:\Path\To\My\Source\Directory";
# Variable contains whitespaces (Program Files (x86))        
String DestinationPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYVAR") + "DestDir";

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"Z:\Path\To\My\BatFile\File.bat";

# "\"" so there should be no problem with whitespaces
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = SourcePath + " \"" + DestinationPath + "\"";
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

try
{
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work ?

I'm open to smarter idea if you have any

Thank you

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Be specific about what problem you are having.

Comment: Are you using the Z: drive when you invoke the batch file directly also? Depending on how the drive was mapped, running as admin might not have the drive mapping available.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway "proc.start() closes instantly" is all I could pull out of my problem

Comment: @elgonzo It works that way, thanks !

Comment: I'll have given in answer, explaining why it didn't work and what to do to make it work. The latter you already know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to start a `.bat` file or a `.cmd` file with rhe `runas` verb, the system looks up the respective command it should execute in the registry.

The registry provides the following command value for the `runas` verb for `.bat` and `.cmd` files:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "%1" %*
```

(`%1` would receive the name of the batch file, `%*` would receive the arguments passed to the batchfile.)

And this command is the cause for the problem. What is missing there are some surrounding quotes around `"%1" %*` (e.g., `""%1" %*"`). cmd.exe will be started (which you notice as a briefly appearing cmd shell window). But the way this command provides the arguments to cmd.exe is not correct, causing cmd.exe to fail starting the batch file.

Editing this registry value would fix the problem for your program. However, i do not suggest you modify this registry entry. It could break other programs, and the problem would still exist on any other machine out there that would one day run your program.

Rather, i suggest to start your batch file in conjunction with `cmd.exe` so you don't rely on the registry's `runas` command implementation for `.bat`/`.cmd` files:

```
var pathToBatchFile = @"Z:\Path\To\My\BatFile\File.bat";
string SourcePath = ...
string DestinationPath = ...

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c \"\"{pathToBatchFile}\" \"{SourcePath}\" \"{DestinationPath}\"\"";
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
...
```

(Note that all arguments following `"cmd.exe /c"` together are framed by a double-quotes pair. Also every single argument itself is put in double-quotes, so this should also work if the source path or the path to the batch file would contain spaces.)